# how to delete image which is stored as varbinary format in database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `PictureBox` with an image and a delete button. The image is stored in a `varbinary(MAX)` format in the database. How do I delete it when the delete button is pressed?

I'm using this code to save an image into the database:

```
byte[] data;

using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    conn.Open();

    Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
    img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    data = stream.ToArray();

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into images values(@images)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@images", data);

    int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

Comment: You will be hard pressed to delete the image, if you have no other field in that table - even if you were binary matching, you could just make sure you delete **one** (or all) such image(s) (a.o.t. a special instance)

Comment: Do you just have a table with one row in it for the image? How do you determine if the image should be loaded from the database (i.e. if it's there)? That should be the key. From what you've said here, the straightforward answer is the statement `delete from images`.

Comment: yea! i have a row in database which has an image in <binary> format! but how should i fire a query? i mean "Delete from images where ?=wat" ??

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the following wouldn't work.

`cmd.CommandText = "delete from images where ID = x";`

Sending plain SQL like this is getting fairly outdated and can be down right dangerous when implemented with a UI improperly, you should strongly consider using LINQ

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query